# Image of an arbitrary map falling on a algebraic set - criterion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f$ be a "typical" smooth non-polynomial map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^7$. Is it reasonable to expect that $f(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is not included within the zero-set of a system of polynomial equations, i.e. not included in an proper algebraic subset of $\mathbb{R}^7$?

Is there any explicit criterion/sufficient condition on $f$ to make sure this does not happen?

Or conversely, if there *is* a system of polynomial $Q$ such that $Q(f)=0$, does it tell us anything particular about $f$?

Edit: of course I don't care about 3 and 7 in particular.

Comment: Say your maps are real analytic but not polynomial. Then the image of $f$ will be a included in the zero set of some analytic equations. It is hardly ever true that those equations are  polynomial. If you move down to the smooth category you have the same situation. All this can be perhaps stated explicitly ( for almost all $f$ in a precise sense: Baire category, measure)

Comment: Thanks. I am now convinced about the typicalness, which is good. What about the case of one specific function (see my comment to Daniel's answer)? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider just the case $\mathbb{R}^1 \to \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. smooth curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  It's not hard to come up with a small arc whose Zariski closure is all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  By replacing an arbitrarily small arc of any given curve with this bad arc, we get a curve which cannot be contained in any proper algebraic subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  So at a minimum we see that the curves which cannot fit in a proper algebraic subset are dense among all curves.

Moreover, if you have a large family of curves, each of which fits in some real algebraic hypersurface, you can do this to all of them simultaneously and get an equally large family of curves, none of which fit in any real algebraic hypersurface.  In fact, you can do it in lots of different ways.  I'm *fairly* sure that rules out the former class having a positive measure in any meaningful sense, but I'm not a functional analyst.

Comment: Thanks. I am happy with the argument for the "typical" aspect. However if I am facing one given function (say given implicitly so I don't have an explicit expression), any idea of how I should approach showing that it cannot be such that $Q(f)=0$? Or I just have to pray I am in the typical case.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by being given a function implicitly?  You mean you have some equation in terms of elementary functions that includes the function somewhere?  Because of course the vast majority of functions can't be written down at all, and the ones that can behave a bit differently from typical functions.

Comment: Yes, an implicit equation $F(x,f(x))=0$. The case I am interested in basically goes: $M_1(A_1 X-\log Y)=M_2(A_2 X-\log(1-Y))$, where $Y$ has dimension $d_y$ (such as 7), $X$ has dimension $d_x$ (such as 3), $M_i$ is square $d_y \times d_y$ , $A_i$ is $d_y \times d_x$, and the matrices are such that I know there is a unique solution $Y \in ]0,1[^{d_y}$ for any $X$.

Comment: What does it mean to take the log of something that's not a number?

Comment: Sorry, by $\log Y$ I mean the vector $(\log y_1, ..., \log y_{d_y})$ (the "vectorized" notation you would use in programming).

Comment: So basically you have an arbitrary system of linear equations in $x_i$ and $\log(y_j)$ and $\log(1-y_j)$, where $y_j$ is a function of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$?  Yeah, you're going to have to come up with an ad-hoc argument for that particular situation.  Knowing the generic behavior usually doesn't help in situations like this.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I have. I was hoping that some sort of big-picture argument would kill it. If $Q(f(x))=0$ then necessarily the derivatives of $f$ such and such, or the behavior of $f$ at infinity such and such, etc. The presence of $\log$ makes me think I am fine, but I could not come up with an argument by hand.

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee that you're not going to find a nice argument for this.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I asked for an ad-hoc comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979980/can-the-image-of-this-specific-function-sit-on-a-variety), let's see if someone is inspired. Ben